Lost keystore password but have .jks, .p12, and .pem files - How can I recover or extract the password?
I recently discovered that my app was removed from the store due to not updating it for some time. I'm now trying to publish a newer version, but I've encountered an issue with my keystore password. Unfortunately, I seem to have misplaced or forgotten the keystore password required for signing the app.
However, I still have the following files related to the keystore:
**.jks
**.p12
**.pem
Is there any method or tool available that can help me extract or recover the keystore password from these files? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Best regards,
Mohamed Okaily

When did you last build the APK keystore? Where is it stored? Usually saved in the key.properties file.
example format key.properties
storePassword="password"
keyPassword="password"
keyAlias=''
storeFile='file jks location'

